# SQL works in phpMyAdmin but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a query that works in phpMyAdmin and returns rows appropriately:

```
"select item_number, general_category from products where key_word_i = 'Floor looms' order by item_number"
```

In my php code, it does not fail, but, returns no rows:

```
$productlist="select item_number, general_category from products where key_word_i = 'Floor looms' order by item_number;";
$productrows = mysql_query($productlist) or die("darn it");
```

If modify the query to just search "key_word_i = 'looms'", it works in both places. To add confusion, I have a local copy and production copy of our products database; the original query in question works correctly in the production database in all instances.

So what could be wrong with my local db? Sure do hope this is something foolishly simple... And apologies for legacy question - I'm moving to PDO just not there with this class yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of useless `'darn it'` and harmful `die()` make it useful and friendly

```
$res = mysql_query($productlist) or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

so, you'd been told what certain error occurred.

Also note that this code is not supposed to return any rows but only a variable of special type - a mysql resource. to get rows you have to iterate over resource, as shown in the example on the manual page

if it still returns no rows - then there are no rows in the database to match your criteria

Comment: It would help if you could tell him, to change that afterwards

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code to include trigger_error, and can confirm that no errors are triggered, simply, no rows are returned. Also, I am aware of the result being a mysql resource and am iterating with "while ($products= mysql_fetch_array($productrows)){" which works correctly when rows are returned.

Comment: Argh, sometimes the truth hurts. There were no rows. In my local environment, I have somewhere switched to the wrong, outdated DB, even where it initially connects to the correct DB. Sorry to have wasted y'alls time. seeing it simply stated triggered me to find the problem. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, this provided the diagnosis: 
    $query="select database(), user()"; $result=mysql_query($query); while($resulty=mysql_fetch_array($result)){print_r($resulty);}

Comment: I had this problem today - the mysql query worked in phpmyadmin, but it didn't worked in my php code. It turned to be the collation, so I just added this code after connecting to the database: mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn); The query worked in phpmyadmin because they already set the collation to utf8. Hope this helps others that deal with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure it is this:

```
"select item_number, general_category  
from products where key_word_i = 'Floor looms' order by item_number;"
```

notice how there is a semicolon ( `;` ) nested in the query.

```
"select item_number, general_category  
   from products where key_word_i = 'Floor looms' order by item_number";
```

is what you want

Comment: +1 I am pretty sure, that was it too. I didn't notice

Comment: @phpNoOb yeah I had to re-read the line of code a few times to notice it.

Comment: Can't believe someone downvoted me and you

Comment: @phpNoOb lol it happens.

Comment: I think it should be required that if you down vote someone, you have to state why.

Comment: Thanks, and, I certainly wish that this were the case! Alas, I have (re)tried that and it doesn't change things...

Comment: @AmosWright is there a stack trace you can share?

Comment: @Woot4Moo I had unwittingly selected an outdated version of the products database after the initial connection. Sadly, a case of an embarrassing mistake rather than something interesting... Thanks for your help.